# How to get a log out of run command in a remote node that is triggered by NodeExecutorResult

Tags: rundeck

I am making a Rundeck plugin in where it uses a node executor to trigger 
a another module in remote. Then I want to verify whether or not this remote command is finished successfully so that I need the log message of the command in remote that the node executor triggered.

```
NodeExecutorResult  ner = jne.executeCommand(context.getExecutionContext(), command, ine);
```

But the NodeExecutorResult above doesn't have any log data  but only have a result code and a result data and failure message and code. How can I get the log?  I am sure that the api exists. Because I can see the log output in the console of rundeck. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

The `NodeExecutorResult` interface has other methods inherited from other interfaces, try the following :

```
NodeExecutorResult  ner = jne.executeCommand(context.getExecutionContext(), command, ine);
String failure message = ner.getFailureMessage();
FailureReason freas = ner.getFailureReason();
Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object> fdata = ner.getFailureData() ;
```

For the `FailureReason` it rather can be a `NodeStepFailureReason` or `StepFailureReason`.

Check their API and the implementations enums :

[FailureReason](http://rundeck.org/2.5.1/javadoc/com/dtolabs/rundeck/core/execution/workflow/steps/FailureReason.html)

[NodeExecutorResult](http://rundeck.org/2.5.1/javadoc/com/dtolabs/rundeck/core/execution/service/NodeExecutorResult.html)

Comment: I already tried running this API. But there is no data in it. If I trigger a command in a remote node, that will return the message "it is successful". But I can not catch this message. But I can see this message printing this in the log output of rundeck console.

Comment: Besides, I have to know the NodeExecutorResult return 
 successfully, I have to get the message from the log and reconfirm that whether or not it works.